# Making a div's height adaptable to the content if it exceeds the initial height

Tags: html, css

I have the following html/css code. What I would like to do is to make `.inner` element's height be adaptable to the content **only if** it exceeds the default minimum height I have set in the code. The below code doesn't allow `.box` elements to stretch beyond the initial height of `.inner`, which I don't want to do. I suspect it has to do with `flex`. If I remove `display:flex;` from `.inner`, the boxes stretch beyond the initial height of `.inner`, but `.inner` doesn't stretch to accommodate the content. I want `.inner` to stretch in this case, while using `display:flex;` or `display:grid;` for `.inner`, otherwise, to behave as I set in my code. How can achieve this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: steelblue;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 70px);
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  background: steelblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-microservice-hmh99?file=/style.css)

Comment: What do you want to happen if the height of an inner (or the sum of the inners' heights) is more than container's height?

Comment: @AHaworth There is only one inner. I guess the container has to stretch to its content too. But the inner's height depends on the container height. So, I am not sure how to handle this. Maybe there is a better way than using percentages?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I meant boxes not inner.

Comment: Please post the picture of the look you want to achieve. I don't really know what you mean by the initial height of .inner because it's defined as 100%. It means the height depends on the parent which is .container... then did you need .inner in the first place... hmmm

Comment: @KoutaNakano That's true, inner height is 100% of the container's height which is set to `height: calc(100vh - 70px);`, so inner **has** an initial height. I need inner to change background color other than the container's.

Comment: @BlackMath so right now, .container's height is fixed by the height property; therefore, .inner's height is fixed too. Do you want to scale .inner's height as depending on the total of box heights inside?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the default minimum height, change height to min-height for .container.

Currently, .container's height property is defined. Therefore, the height does not scale.